# Bootstrap 4 media-queries mixins not working with Bootstrap 4 via CDN

Tags: sass, gulp, media-queries, bootstrap-4, mixins

I'm using bootstrap 4 connected via CDN, all works fine, but only mixins not working. I have this error in php storm: "Cannot find mixin 'media-breakpoint-down'. This inspection warns about sass/scss mixins references which can't be resolved to any valid target."

And this in terminal:

Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    sass\styles.scss
Error: no mixin named media-breakpoint-down

```
   Backtrace:
    sass/styles.scss:365
    on line 365 of sass/styles.scss
```

> > @include media-breakpoint-down(xs) {
> >        ---------^

This is how i'm using it in scss file: `@include media-breakpoint-down(xs) { }`

This is how I connecting bootstrap 4:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
      </head>
      <body>

        <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./project/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe (autoprefixer('last 3 versions', '> 5%'))
        .pipe (minifyCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./project/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
})

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./project/**/*scss', ['sass']);
})

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./project",
    });

    gulp.watch("./project/sass/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("./project/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: Gulp has nothing to do with the css loaded from the CDN.  What's the content of the _./project/sass/styles.scss_ file?

Comment: it's styles for the html page

Comment: No surprise in that. But what's the exact content? I guess you have `@include media-breakpoint-down` on line 365. If so, do you include the  bootstrap scss files somewhere?

Comment: no, I just connected bootstrap 4 in the HTML file as shown here - https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start and that's it. All functionality of bootstrap works, but only mixins not.

Answer (score 24):

Before importing the bootstrap 4 mixins, import these resources in this exact order:

```
@import "~bootstrap-4.0.0/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "~bootstrap-4.0.0/scss/_variables.scss";
@import "~bootstrap-4.0.0/scss/mixins/_breakpoints.scss";
```

Now it is possible to write something like this:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  .some-class {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this on an Angular project and it doesn't work. I still get the error

`
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
    @mixin media-breakpoint-up($name, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {

    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_breakpoints.scss 58:49  media-breakpoint-up()
`

Answer (score 8):

The error here is coming from a Gulp process, but it has nothing to do with the bootstrap css loaded from CDN in your html. In fact, the css there is the already compiled version of bootstrap, which incorporates the results of the `@mixin media-breakpoint-down` in the form of css styles.

As the error states, you are trying to use the `@mixin media-breakpoint-down` on line 365 in your *sass/styles.scss* file, but apparently the scss mixin is not defined. To make use of the bootstrap mixins in your custom scss you have to `@import` at least the *functions.scss*, *variables.scss* and *mixins.scss* files from the bootstrap scss library at the top of your file.

```
// At the top of "sass/styles.scss"
@import "[path_to_bootstrap]/functions";
@import "[path_to_bootstrap]/variables";
@import "[path_to_bootstrap]/mixins";

.test-class {
  @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
    display: block;
    // …
  }
}
```

In case you do not have the bootstrap scss files ready in your project folder, you can install that by one of the methods listed at http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/#package-managers. (E.g.: `$ npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2` with npm.) Once the lib is there, you have to make the imports above.

Now, another step could be to import the whole bootstrap system into your scss file (by `@import "[path_to_bootstrap]/bootstrap";`). In this case you could remove the css link from your html, as your *styles.css* would contain the entire library.

Comment: when I trying to import the functions.scss, variables.scss and mixins.scss files from the bootstrap scss library I have this in the terminal: Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    project\sass\_mixins.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: mixins/breakpoints.
       Parent style sheet: D:/GeekHub Frontend+cms/hw8/project/sass/_mixins.scss
        on line 6 of project/sass/_mixins.scss
>> @import "mixins/breakpoints";
   ^

Comment: That simply means Gulp tries to access the file at `/project/sass/mixins/_breakpoints.scss`, but it either does not exists or it is unreadable. Did you copy the files manually?

Comment: This worked perfectly for my ReactJS project. Kudos.